# Angular: ngClass conditional not being applied on mouse movement

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to apply a class to my element when the mouse stops moving.  It seems I have I can detect when the mouse moves or stops (see console) but I don't know why it's not applying the style when my mouse stops moving.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lg2p6f?file=src/app/app.component.html

HTML:

```
<div
  class="wrapper"
  (mouseenter)="enter()"
  (mousemove)="move($event)"
  (mouseleave)="leave()"
>
  <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
  <div class="sites-circle" [ngClass]="mouseMove ? 'onMove' : 'notMove'">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
  enter(source: string) {
    this.tooltip.classList.add('show');
  }

  mouseStopped() {
    this.mouseMove = false;
    console.log("mousemove: " + this.mouseMove);
  }

  move(e: { pageX: number; pageY: number }) {

    this.mouseMove = true;
    console.log("mousemove: " + this.mouseMove);

    var timer;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(this.mouseStopped, 300);

    const tooltipStyle = this.tooltip.style;

    tooltipStyle.left = e.pageX + 'px';
    tooltipStyle.top = e.pageY + 'px';
  }

  leave() {
    this.tooltip.classList.remove('show');
  }
```

CSS:

```
.sites-circle.onMove {
  transform: scale(3);
}
.sites-circle.notMove {
  transform: scale(1) !important;
}
```

Comment: I would use a `BehaviorSubject` holding the mouse position. Then just do `this.mousePos$.pipe(debounce(600)).subscribe((pos) => this.isMoving = false)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in the setTimeout case the `this` keyword is pointing to the global/window object not the Component itself.

Writing the setTimeout with an arrow function will solve the problem as it doesn't have its own value of `this` and will access its value from its lexical scope.

```
 timer = setTimeout(() => { this.mouseStopped() }, 300);
```